# Wordpress how to force redirect page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

Here is my situation.
I have the 'me' page which parent page is 'about'.
So if I type the url 'mysite.com/me' then it goes to 'mysite.com/about/me' automatically.
My requirement:
When I type 'mysite.com/me/profile', I hope it goes to 'othersite.com/myprofile'.
But it always goes to 'mysite.com/about/me' automatically.
What I tried:
- At first, I added redirect rule in .htaccess file.
Redirect 301 /me/profile othersite.com/myprofile
But no success. 
- Then I created an empty page with 'me' title. I created another 'profile' page and set the 'me' page as it's parent. I created a new page template and add header() function only.

```
<?php
header("Location: othersite.com/myprofile");
?>
```

I set the page template as the 'profile' page's template.
But in any cases, no lucks. It always goes to 'mysite.com/about/me'.
Any advice?

Comment: did you try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/

Comment: yes, but same result.